# How is HTML injection possible in this domxss.com challenge

Tags: html, jquery, xss, owasp, html-injections

OWASP's testing for HTML injection page ([link](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/11-Client-side_Testing/03-Testing_for_HTML_Injection)) shows a particular code that is supposed to be vulnerable to HTML injection.

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
function setMessage(){
    var t=location.hash.slice(1);
    $("div[id="+t+"]").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
}
$(document).ready(setMessage  );
$(window).bind("hashchange",setMessage)
</script>
<body>
    <script src="../js/embed.js"></script>
    <span><a href="#message" > Show Here</a><div id="message">Showing Message1</div></span>
    <span><a href="#message1" > Show Here</a><div id="message1">Showing Message2</div>
    <span><a href="#message2" > Show Here</a><div id="message2">Showing Message3</div>
</body>
```

This code is one of the challenges on ([domxss.com](http://www.domxss.com/domxss/01_Basics/06_jquery_old_html.html)) and I am unsure of how this is vulnerable.

From what I understand, the URL's hash can be used as an input and any change in the URL will trigger the `setMessage` function. This URL hash will be my payload. However, this payload is only being used as a selector in jQuery which is where I hit a wall.

I am relatively new to XSS so any payloads will be appreciated. An explanation is obviously welcome.

Also, any resources to better understand HTML injection attacks via jQuery will be useful.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used jQuery, but jQuery can also create new elements with its constructor.  Something like `$('<script src="evil.js"></script>')`.  Not sure if that works in the context of that selector or not... might be worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, very old versions of jQuery are vulnurable to XSS from a dynamic selector string. See [Bug # 11290](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11290) on jQuery's bug tracker - if formulated just right, the selector string can be accidentally interpreted as HTML. If the selector string can be provided by the user, you could be in trouble.

For a minimal example:

```js
$(`div[class='<img src="" onerror=alert("evil")>]`).text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So, the original

```
$("div[id="+t+"]")
```

can be injected with such a `t` that results in arbitrary code running.

```js
const t = `'<img src="" onerror=alert("evil")>]`;
$("div[id="+t+"]").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The bug was fixed 9 years ago, so unless you're deliberately using an ancient version of jQuery and never update your dependencies, it probably won't affect you.

The bug was ultimate caused by [an insufficiently strict regex.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/7692ae419d4c19bd06a0ba01fc2af8d21035873c).

Comment: The linked bug fix indeed mentions that it is supposed to fix "xss attack via hash"