# How prevent DOM XSS

Tags: jquery, xss

I have function to get radio button value.

```
var val = $('input[name="test_'+ id + 
'"]:checked').val();
```

but it cause DOM XSS. How do I refactor to prevent XSS?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not have an XSS vulnerability except in [extremely ancient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70048641) versions of jQuery, so it's probably not something to worry about.

Avoiding jQuery and using `querySelector` will work though.

```
const val = document.querySelector('input[name="test_'+ id + '"]:checked').value;
```